# Ifelse conditional on same strings in multiple columns

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

So I guess this is possible to achieve by just making a veeery long line code using mutate() and ifelse() but I want to know if there is a way of doing it without writing a tone of code.

I have data where the degree of each individual is written in a non-ordered fashion. The data looks like this:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
degree1 <- c("masters", "bachelors", "PhD", "bachelors", "bachelors", NA)
degree2 <- c("PhD", "masters", "bachelors", NA, NA, NA)
degree3 <- c("bachelors", NA, "masters", NA, "masters", NA)
```

Now I want to create a new column containing the string for the highest degree, like this

```
dat$highest_degree <- c("PhD", "masters", "PhD", "bachelors", "masters", NA)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to loop over the rows for the selected 'degree' column, convert to `factor` with `levels` specified in the order, drop the levels to remove the unused levels and select the `first` `level`

```
v1 <- c("PhD", "masters", "bachelors")
dat$highest_degree <- apply(dat[-1], 1, function(x)  
        levels(droplevels(factor(x, levels = v1)))[1])
dat$highest_degree
#[1] "PhD"       "masters"   "PhD"       "bachelors" "masters"   NA
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, reshape into 'long' format, then `slice` the first row after `arrange`ing the long format column by `match`ing with an ordered degree vector and grouping by 'id', then join with the original data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% 
     pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('degree'), values_to = 'highest_degree') %>%
     select(-name) %>% 
     arrange(id, match(highest_degree, v1)) %>% 
     group_by(id) %>%
     slice_head(n = 1) %>%
     ungroup %>% 
     left_join(dat, .)
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(id, degree1, degree2, degree3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `pmin` + `factor`

```
lvs <- c("PhD", "masters", "bachelors")
dat$highest_degree <- lvs[
  do.call(
    pmin,
    c(asplit(matrix(as.integer(factor(as.matrix(dat[-1]), levels = lvs)), nrow(dat)), 2),
      na.rm = TRUE
    )
  )
]
```

which gives

```
> dat
  id   degree1   degree2   degree3 highest_degree
1  1   masters       PhD bachelors            PhD
2  2 bachelors   masters      <NA>        masters
3  3       PhD bachelors   masters            PhD
4  4 bachelors      <NA>      <NA>      bachelors
5  5 bachelors      <NA>   masters        masters
6  6      <NA>      <NA>      <NA>           <NA>
```

**Data**

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), degree1 = c("masters",
"bachelors", "PhD", "bachelors", "bachelors", NA), degree2 = c("PhD",
"masters", "bachelors", NA, NA, NA), degree3 = c("bachelors",
NA, "masters", NA, "masters", NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```